# php: in_array() with Arabic

Tags: php, arrays, arabic

I'm using `in_array` function with arabic language...
`in_array ('من', $words)` gave true where $words really includes `من`.

but `in_array('من', $stopWords)` is giving false although it includes the word من...

```
print_r($stopWords);
```

give:

> Array ( [0] => من )

and `print_r($words);`

give:

> Array ( [0] => من )

What could be the problem?

Comment: Try `var_dump(bin2hex($stopWords[0]))` and the same on your needle string and see if they're the same.

Comment: The most likely explanation is that the two comparison strings are stored in a different character set. Are you defining the array and doing the check in the same PHP file? If not, are you 100% sure both are in the same encoding?

Comment: Perhaps one of the text string actually contains code-points from the presentation range. Another possibility is that there's a kasra or fatha on the nuun and you're not seeing it because your the editor is using a crappy font that doesn't position vowel marks correctly. Most likely there's just a space in front or behind the word.

Comment: $words is defined by me (and I'm sure it's utf-8) but $stopWords is taken from text file (windows) like the following:
$stopText  = file_get_contents( $stopWordsFilename );
$stopWords = mb_split( '[ \n]', $stopText); 
I think the problem should be relevant to this issue...

Comment: Did you tried to use mb_strlen() on both strings to get exact char length? It might be that these words in UTF-8 have different char length although appear to look same because of bad font.

Comment: @IvanHušnjak that's right...
$stopWords[0] give 3 while $words[0] give 2 but the same word...
I'm really confused... is there any solution?

Comment: one solution might be to replace that "extra" char in $stopText with empty before calling mb_split... but that might arose some other problems. Other solution would be to convert text to utf using iconv() or mb_convert_encoding()

Comment: @Adnan I know Arabic and i know those 'harakat'... both texts don't have any 'harakat'... i've found the problem.. there is a space before 'من' in $stopWords[0] so it's not the same word in $words[0]...to solve this i'm using `mb_strpos` for each array element instead of `in_array`...

Answer (score 0):

You should use [unicode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php) for this. If you convert arabic letter to unicode. And you can check in array. And you don't have any problem.

Answer (score 0):

$stopWords[0] is 'من ' with a space before من.
so since i have to deal with real text file and reflex it into $stopWords, I can't modify it..
instead of that.. I'm using mb_strpos to catch any occurrence of the word 'من' in any element of the array $stopWords..
and that's it... problem solved..